# Find subarray with fixed end and largest average of any length

Tags: python, algorithm

So here I am given an array - array1 with N positive integers in [0, 10000]. N might be up to 10^8. **Given that we need to fix the end point**, what is the continuous subarray with the largest average possible?

For example, let array1 be [3, 1, 9, 2, 7]. Since we fix the end point, the subarray with the largest average possible is [9, 2, 7], with average 6.

I have tried a purely linear search, though Python is slow at looping 10^8 loops so it is not a good algorithm.

Time Restriction - The time limit is 4 seconds.

EDIT: I really don't have idea to start improving, so any hints would be appreciated. Is it possible to reduce it to O(log n)?

Clarification: The Last element is needed to be in the subarray and the subarray's length need to be >1

Comment: I dont understand, the subarray with the highest average would be `[9]` here? Since you say *"largest average of any length"*. This would be a subarray of length 1.

Comment: I need to fix the end point, I should edit the wordings. The subarray needs to include the last element.

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ That makes more sense. My only issue is that even if the subarray includes the last element, wouldn't the highest average now be `[7]`? Unless the sub array needs to be bigger than length 1. I think this ambiguity needs to be clarified.

Comment: Also what have you tried so far? So we can have a better idea on how to improve your algorithm.

Comment: You are right. English isn't my main language so sorry. I have tried linear search as said, but it was too slow.

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ Have you already tried something like [this](https://ideone.com/0mlMWB)?

Comment: Can you explain how it works? I am new to python & itertools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to do this task:

```
def sublists(l, minsize, endpoint):

    # create empty list of all candidate sublists
    # O(1) 
    candidates = []

    # obtain the possible sublists
    # O(n) 
    for start, end in combinations(range(len(l)), minsize):

        # check if last element is the endpoint
        # O(1) 
        if l[end] == endpoint:

            # add sublist to the candidates
            # O(1) 
            candidates.append(l[start:end+1])

    # create tuple pairs (average, sublist)
    # O(n)
    pairs = [(sum(x) / len(x), x) for x in candidates]

    # get max sublist
    # O(n)
    return max(pairs)[1]
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> print(sublists([3, 1, 9, 2, 7], 2, 7))
[9, 2, 7]
```

**Note:** The algorithm above is `O(n)`. This is expected since you need to create all possible contiguous combinations of the list to begin with. I don't think you can do this algorithm in `O(logn)` time, since generating the combinations itself is `O(n)`. If you use a balanced BST you could perhaps find the maximum average in `O(logn)` time, but this would just be for the search part, not the algorithm as a whole.